Writing action-angle coordinates as an elliptic-integral. Figuring out the Liouville/Symplectic form on the reduced space given by an $S^1$-action
I have the following situation. Let $(M,\omega)$ be a $4$-dimensional Symplectic manifold and $F=(J,H):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $(M,\omega,F)$ is a completely integrable system. Furthermore suppose that $J$ induces an $S^1$-action. Furthermore, let us look at the reduced space $J^{-1}(j)/S^1$, which sometimes may be singular.
The goal here is to compute the action-angle coordinates of the system. Since $J$ generates an $S^1$-action one of them is trivially given by $J$ and therefore we only need to compute the other one. I would like to do this looking at the reduced space, i.e., consider $H_{red}:J^{-1}(j)/S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $\beta_{l,h}$ be the curve in $J^{-1}(j)/S^1$ be defined by $H_{red}=h$. Therefore in order to compute the second action coordinate we need to compute $\oint_{\beta_{l,h}}\alpha_{red}$ where $\alpha_{red}$ is the primitive of the symplectic form in the reduced space. I was wondering if there is a good way to obtain an expression for this "Liouville" form using the equations for the reduced space. Let us look at an example to make this more precise.
Suppose that the reduced space $J^{-1}(j)/S^1$ is given by the equations $\pi_5^2+\pi_6^2=\pi_1^2\pi_3\pi_4$, $\pi_1+\pi_2+2\pi_3=6$ and $\pi_3+\pi_4=2$ where $\pi_j=x_j^2+y_j^2$ for $j=1,...,4$ and $\pi_5=\Re(\overline{z_1}z_3\overline{z_4})$ and $\pi_6=\Im(\overline{z_1}z_3\overline{z_4})$, where $z_k=x_k+iy_k$.
Furthermore in this example $H=\pi_5$ and $J=\pi_2/2$. Therefore the dynamics in the reduced space are given by $\dot{\pi_k}:=\{\pi_k,\pi_5\}$. I was wondering if there is a way to write the integral $\oint_{\beta_{l,h}}\alpha_{red}$ using these dynamics, in order to write it as an elliptic integral?
What I mean by this is the following. Suppose we want to compute the first return time $T(j,h)$ of $(j,h)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e., how long it takes for the $J$ orbit to intersect the $H$ orbit for certain $(j,h)$ values. Then in order to do this we do the following
\begin{equation}
T(j,h)=\int_{0}^{T(j,h)}dt=2\int_{\pi_3^{-}}^{\pi_3^{+}}\frac{d\pi_3}{\dot{\pi_3}}=\int_{\pi_3^{-}}^{\pi_3^{+}}\frac{d\pi_3}{\sqrt{S(j,h)}}
\end{equation}
where $\pi_3^{\pm}$ are the roots of the polynomial $S(j,h):=(6-2\pi_3-2j)\pi_3(2-\pi_3)-h^2$. The polynomial shows up due to the fact $\dot{\pi_3}=\{\pi_3,\pi_5\}=-2\pi_6$ and $\pi_5^2+\pi_6^2=\pi_1^2\pi_3\pi_4$.
So it all this being said is there a similar approach that I can do to write the integral $\oint_{\beta_{l,h}}\alpha_{red}$ as an elliptic integral ? I would do the same change of variable, introducing $\pi_3$ but I am not sure what happens with $\alpha_{red}$ so any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
